# How to create test plan when there is one website and one tester

Tags: manual-testing, web-application, test-planning

I want to create a test plan for one website which is of medium size. I have got many test plan templates from the internet but those are too lengthy and perfect for testing team and big websites.

Also, I am a little confused about what should I remove and what I need to add in that predefined test plan template.

So is there any perfect test plan template which I can use for one website and I am the only tester. In future, I will have to follow the same plan. So I need a test plan template which is enough for one tester and medium website testing.

**Note:** I will customize test plan according to website specification but for starting I need generic template which suit above need.

Comment: You just try out "Testrail" to create test plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is there any perfect test plan template which I can use for one
>   website and I am only tester.

No. There is no such thing as a "perfect test plan template". Instead of perfection, strive for "good enough for your needs".

Since you are the sole tester, start out with something simple. Note what you are testing, when you are testing, the environment you are using for testing, and the tests you expect to execute.

Grow this template as your needs change.

These might give you some ideas: http://www.allthingsquality.com/search/label/Templates

> In future I will have to follow same plan. So I need test plan
>   template which is enough for one tester and medium website testing.

If your needs change, the application changes, others are recruited to help, etc - it doesn't make sense to follow exactly the same plan.

If you are being told that you must anyway, you might want to ask why. Be guided by the response you get.

Answer (score 4):

For most apps start by testing:

- signup
- login
- logout
- edit user info
- delete user (admin)
- add item
- edit item
- delete item

for each of the above test:

- happy....   The user uses expected values and defaults, Minimal approach
- sad........     The user uses invalid values and gets error messages
- options.. The user adds optional or additional information, maximal approach

Consider testing in 4 quadrants:

```
              |
  Integrated  |  Performance
  __________________________
              |
  Unit        |  Exploratory
```

And using the testing triangle

```
              ui tests                    |     few (dozens)
           integrated tests              /|\
          individual unit tests         /\/\/\  many (thousands)
```

Once you've got all the above tested you'll likely have a good sense of what to test next.

Answer (score 2):

For Medium size web application,you can write a test plan from the Software testing help , in which all description wise all field name is displayed and also one sample of test plan is also displayed, you can use it, from the below Link:

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/how-to-write-test-plan-document-software-testing-training-day3/

Answer (score 1):

> So is there any perfect test plan template which I can use for one website and I am only tester

I don't think you will find this perfect test plan on the web. It is upon you to modify the closest one to suit to your needs.

I have found this website to be extremely helpful which searching for artifacts/resources related to SW Testing :
[Vietnamese Testing Board](http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/)

If you search for the test plan and then go to the FILE tab in the search results, you'll find a lot of good documents.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: @log_file the above link, when clicked on, says "Not Found"

Comment: I will update this link. Give me some time

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a mind map instead of a traditional test plan. It will provide you a document artifact and be lighter weight since your project is medium sized. People can still collaborate on it if need be by adding / updating nodes.

[xmind](https://www.xmind.net/)
or [freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) are pretty popular choices.

Answer (score 0):

For medium size web applications, you can see this guide How to write a test plan with the IEEE 829 standard. Please go with link as per below:
https://reqtest.com/testing-blog/how-to-write-a-test-plan-2/

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation to your website, or you risk your answer being deleted as spam. See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/promotion for more information.